# Span and list elements wrap in DIV

Tags: javascript, css, html, list, html-lists

I have tried to combine a span element and a list that uses in-block formatting. There seems to be so misalignment of the elements.

Also, would anyone know how to wrap the elements within a fixed width?

Her's a link

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/joewaldronrit/3nhdnbL8/#&togetherjs=97QmIzvPKD>?
```

CSS:

```
.word-sugg-hint{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    color:rgb(32,106,138);
}

.sugg-details{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}

ul.suggestion-list li{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:0px;
}

ul.suggestion-list{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom:3px;
}

ul.suggestion-list li:hover{
    color:rgb(105, 131, 73);
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;

}

ul.suggs.suggestion-list li{
/*
    width:180px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    */
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    color:#0000FF;
    font-size:14px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var crateItems = ["apples", "bananas", "grapefruit"];
var suggList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");
for (var i = 0; i < suggList.children.length; i++) {
    if (crateItems.length === i) break;
    suggList.children[i].innerHTML =  crateItems[i]  + (i < crateItems.length - 1 ? "," : "");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="word-sugg-hint" id ="sugg-div">
                                <h class="sugg-details"> Did you mean? </h>
                                <ul id="suggestion-list" class="suggestion-list suggs">

                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                    <li>

                                    </li>
                                </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Post the code in the question... Do not try to get around the jsfiddle restriction.

Comment: OK, but its a formatting error. Will post soon, sorry.

Comment: What's kind of element is `<h>`? You also need to remove the padding and margin from your list, and float it if you want it to align with your other floated element.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that instead of an `<h>` element, you mean `<span>`.

The main reason your elements were misaligned was your `float:left` was clashing with your `display: inline-block`. That solved your first problem. Your second question, how to wrap elements within a fixed width. If you see my jsFiddle, I simply wrapped the span and ul with a div that had a class called 'wrap'. I gave that element a fixed width. I also gave it a background color so you can easily see the width of each div. Because div's are block elements, I had to make it display as inline-block. You will see the text is aligned, and the widths are the same. Take away the background color, and I think it renders the way you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/3nhdnbL8/2/

As a greater take away, may I suggest, when working with CSS to get the desired look, too often we keep adding stuff. It is important to remember that when you add something, that may clash with something that already exists. Each time you want to add something, I would first ask if there is anything you should take out. It is a good idea to plan our CSS the same way we plan our JavaScript. Too much CSS causes a great deal of conflicts, and can become very difficult to debug.

Good luck.

Comment: It looks like someone messed with your div a little bit. It was actually quite useful before.

Comment: I checked my fiddle, and the div's were stacking because I gave them a fixed width, as per your question, and my window wasn't wide enough to allow for both. I changed it to a %. I don't know exactly what you want the outcome to look like, but if you think I answered your question, can you accept it? If I didn't answer, please tell me what is missing. Thanks.